# Concatenating qt-specific keyword and macro argument with a space in between

Tags: c++, qt, concatenation, c-preprocessor

My problem is quite simple. I want the following macro

```
#define PROXYPASS(name, param) \
void MyClass::sl_name(param _param) { \
    emit name(_param); \
}
```

to expand `PROXYPASS(clientAdded, Client*)` to:

```
void MyClass::sl_clientAdded(Client* _param) { \
    emit clientAdded(_param); \
}
```

but since it ain't working i.e. it still shows just `sl_name` instead of `sl_clientAdded`. So, this is what I'm using:

```
#define PROXYPASS(name, param) \
void MyClass::sl_ ## name(param _param) { \
    emit ## name(_param); \
}
```

It works fine, other than the fact that it expands to:

```
void MyClass::sl_clientAdded(Client* _param) { \
    emitclientAdded(_param); \
}
```

Everything is fine other than the fact that there is no space between `emit` and `clientAdded` i.e. it expands to `emitclientAdded` instead of `emit clientAdded`. So how do I go about doing it? Is there a way to add spaces, or must I look for another way. A lot of googling has got my hopes down due to the following statement: *Whether it [gcc pre-processor] puts white space between the tokens is undefined.*

My other failed attempts include

```
emit ## ## name(_param);
emit ## /* */ ## name(_param);
emit ## \ ## name(_param);
emit /* */ ## name(_param);
emit ## space ## name(_param); [#define space \ ]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**NOTE:** Preprocessor output and macro expansion checked using `gcc -E myclass.cpp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put nothing there, you don't need to concatenate anything:

```
#define PROXYPASS(name, param) \
void MyClass::sl_ ## name(param _param) { \
    emit name(_param); \
}
```

Comment: `emit name(_param)` expands to only `clientAdded(_param);`. For some strange reason the `emit` keyword is simply gobbled. I do think it is because it is not standard C++, because if I change it to `int name(_param)`, it expands properly with `int clientAdded(_param);`. I think it is because `emit` in itself is a macro.

Comment: Yes, it is exactly so. The `emit` "keyword" expands to nothing, it has no real meaning. Qt's signals behave like, and in fact are functions, and can be called without `emit`.

Comment: thanks a lot. I guess I was doing what was required all along :)